# Is there any way to respond in code to a Mac terminal window changing its contents?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I'm doing some embedded C++ development and I have a call stack being printed from my device to a Mac terminal via a UART.
I'd like to create a C++ app that somehow listens to the terminal output, detects a callstack, and automatically converts the addresses into symbols.
I can do the conversion, but I'm not sure if there's a way for my app to be notified when the terminal output has changed, or even to periodically poll the open terminals and extract their contents?

Comment: Couldn't you just redirect all output to your program and then parse that out?

Comment: Not really, because it's running on an external embedded device, and transferring the output from that device to the Mac via a UART.

Comment: How are you pulling the data from the UART? It's got to be plugged in to your Mac some how, like an FTDI/USB controller of some sort correct? That then has to be opened via some com port in your terminal .. You could redirect all com output to your program in that sense